# How to find largest image in a list

Tags: jquery

I have the following `HTML` structure:

```
<ul id="list2">
  <li class="_column small">
    <img id="YB_random_with_img" src="/cms_agency/Images/CharterWebsite/W350xH300/Articles-(7)-350-300.jpg" alt="Home " title="Home " />
     <h2><a href="/cms_agency/more/articles/articles-(7)">Greece</a></h2>

  </li>
  <li class="_column small">
    <img id="YB_random_with_img" src="/cms_agency/Images/CharterWebsite/W720xH300/Articles-(1)-720-300.jpg" alt="Home " title="Home " />
     <h2><a href="/cms_agency/more/articles/articles-(1)">Stockholm</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li class="_column small">
    <img id="YB_random_with_img" src="/cms_agency/Images/CharterWebsite/W350xH300/Articles-350-300.jpg" alt="Home " title="Home " />
     <h2><a href="/cms_agency/more/articles/articles">Sailing in Italy</a></h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My problem is that it doesn't find the largest image in the `._column` and sometimes applies a width that is smaller than the largest image and is creating problems with my layout.

I have the following code:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("._column img").each(function () {
            if (this.width > 350) {
                jQuery(this.parentNode).addClass('large');
            }
            else {
                jQuery(this.parentNode).addClass('small');
            }

        });
    });
```

Some sugestions? Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend you to place this code inside of the .load() function..

Comment: Are you actually trying to set the width of each `<li>` that contains the image, or the `<ul>`..?

Comment: Yes, work with load() function . Thank you so much. But why with load and not with ready?

Comment: @AndreeaTirgovatu `ready()` fires when the `DOM` structure is created, `load` fires when the resources are loaded...

Answer (score 1):

From the docs of [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready):

> In cases where code relies on loaded assets (for example, if the dimensions of an image are required), the code should be placed in a handler for the load event instead.

So we should to use [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event) event rather than [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) so that the correct dimensions are retrieved after images are loaded:

```
jQuery(document.body).load(function () {
  var largest;
  jQuery("._column img").each(function () {
    if(!largest)
        largest = this.width;
    else if(this.width>largest)
        largest= this.width;
  });
});
```

Comment: can you try using `$(document.body).load()` instead of `$(document).ready()` ..?

Comment: Work with load(). Thanks!